# How to get body from a post request in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, express

I am sending data `id` using post method to my node server. But `req.body` is undefined in my node file

My index.html looks like this:

```
<html ng-app="IMDBApp">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="testController as movieFetcher" class="container">
        <input type="text" ng-model="movieFetcher.movieId"></input>
        <button ng-click="movieFetcher.sendId(movieFetcher.movieId)">Fetch Details</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

My Angular Controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('testController',['$http',function($http){
this.movieId = 197;
this.sendId = function(id){
    $http.post('/test',id).success(function(response){
     // does something on response
    });
}; }]);
```

My node server looks like :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.listen(8080);


app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
 var i = req.body;
 var url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt' + i + '/';
 // i shows as undefined
 console.log("i is",i,"url is",url);
 res.send(url);
});
```

Comment: Have you opened your network tab to confirm angular is sending that value in the request body? Are you sure the correct contentType is set by angular as needed for `bodyParser.text()`?

Comment: i got it. I was not setting the `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http.post` by default sends a Content-Type of `application/json`, since you're using `text/plain` you'll need to explicitly send over a Content-Type of `text/plain`.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/test',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  },
  data: id
})
```

> #### From [`$http Docs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) Setting HTTP Headers
>
> The $http service will automatically add certain HTTP headers to all requests. These defaults can be fully configured by accessing the $httpProvider.defaults.headers configuration object, which currently contains this default configuration:
>
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common (headers that are common for all requests): Accept: application/json, text/plain, * / *`
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST requests)
>     Content-Type: application/json`
> - `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put (header defaults for PUT requests)
>     Content-Type: application/json`

Answer (score 0):

update your `server.js` to

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

instead of

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
```

Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the incoming JSON to a string, 
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            var params = JSON.parse(body);
            //callback function
            callback;
        });

Then read your data like body.id